# Google Sheets - Try to do sumifs with 2 conditions on a merged cells

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have this situation on google sheets

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIlSh.png)

I wanted to make a monthly report with `sumifs` with 2 conditions like the image above. But all I got was errors.

Code I am using

`=sumifs(D2:D13;D1:G1;C16;B2:B13;or(B2:B13="apple","cherry","watermelon"))`

Comment: Don’t think or() works luke that at least not in Excel.

Comment: You should not have `merge cells` if want to perform calculation, as the value only match first row item only which is `apple`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use combination of multiple `sumifs` to solve your calculation since you won't know which will be the first row item that has `market value` and sum of amount of other fruits will return 0, therefore the calculation will still give correct total.

```
=SUMIFS($D$2:$D$13,$B$2:$B$13,B17)+SUMIFS($D$2:$D$13,$B$2:$B$13,B18)+SUMIFS($D$2:$D$13,$B$2:$B$13,B19)
```

[image]

Comment: this is exactly what i needed. Thank you

Comment: Welcome, I was first thought it is impossible, at least it prove `sumifs` still very useful :)